# SDL Stream for C++ follow up

Tags: c++, stream, sdl

Initial review requested [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/282510/507):

The big thing I had missed was that read/write either work successfully (and all requested data is read/written) or it fails the flags are set appropriately.

For write this is easy. It work and we can return `num` or it fails and we return -1.

For read it is slightly more complex. A read that gets data but hits `eof()` has still worked (but my original function would have returned -1 indicating failure). So a read fails if the `eof()` is true before the read is tried or one of the following is true `bad()` or `fail()` or `gcount() == 0` after the read is done.

```
/*
 * If we read and reach eof() that is still a good read (as long as data is read)
 * So this test does not check for eof() as a failure.
 *
 * Note: if eof() is true then the next call to streamReadThor()
 *       will result in a failure, as it test to see if the stream
 *       is good before a read.
 */
bool streamHadGoodRead(std::istream& stream)
{
    return !stream.bad() && !stream.fail() && stream.gcount() != 0;
}

/*
 * Reads `num` objects of size `size` from the stream.
 * Return -1 on failure or the number of objects read.
 */
size_t streamReadThor(SDL_RWops* input, void* dst, size_t size, size_t num)
{
    ThorSDLStreamRead*  data = static_cast<ThorSDLStreamRead*>(input);
    if (!data->stream) {
        return -1;
    }
    data->stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(dst), num * size);
    return streamHadGoodRead(data->stream) ? data->stream.gcount() / size : -1;
}

/*
 * Write `num` objects of size `size` to the stream.
 * Return -1 on failure or the number of objects written.
 */
size_t streamWriteThor(SDL_RWops* output, const void* src, size_t size, size_t num)
{
    ThorSDLStreamWrite*  data = static_cast<ThorSDLStreamWrite*>(output);
    if (!data->stream) {
        return -1;
    }
    data->stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(src), num * size);
    return data->stream ? num : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the comments match the code. In `streamHadGoodRead()` the comments talk about `eof()`, but the code doesn't contain any `eof()`.

Furthermore, the code is still not correct. Read the documentation of [`std::ifstream::read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) carefully: you'll notice that on reaching the end of the file, it will set both `eofbit` *and* `failbit`.

I also checked the documentation for [`SDL_RWops`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_RWops): apparently, `read()` should return 0 on error or EOF, not -1. That also means that you don't need to special case for `gcount() == 0`. Also, `write()` should return the number of objects that were fully written, and not -1 on error.

```
/*
 * Read `num` objects of size `size` from the stream.
 * Return the number of objects successfully read,
 * which might be less than num if an error occurred or EOF has been reached.
 */
size_t streamReadThor(SDL_RWops* input, void* dst, size_t size, size_t num)
{
    auto& stream = static_cast<ThorSDLStreamRead*>(input)->stream;
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(dst), num * size);
    return stream.gcount() / size;
}

/*
 * Write `num` objects of size `size` to the stream.
 * Return the number of objects successfully written,
 * which might be less than num if an error occurred.
 */
size_t streamWriteThor(SDL_RWops* output, const void* src, size_t size, size_t num)
{
    auto& stream = static_cast<ThorSDLStreamWrite*>(output)->stream;

    if (!stream)
        return 0;

    auto before = stream.tellp();
    stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(src), num * size);
    return (stream.tellp() - before) / size;
}
```

Note that `std::ostream::write()` does not set `failbit` on error, so `tellp()` would still be valid after a write error. However, if `failbit` was set because of any other action on the stream, then `tellp()` cannot be used, so we still need the check if the stream is good before doing anything.